# What is the difference between multi-link flexible manipulators and continuum robots?

Tags: dynamics, manipulator

I read the review[1] on flexible manipulators, the modeling method of multi-link(even if single-link) flexible manipulators seems very different from the continuum robots like OctArm(multi-section), hyper-redundant manipulator and etc which based on the backbone curve or constant curvature model.

[1]Sayahkarajy, Mostafa, Z. Mohamed, and Ahmad Athif Mohd Faudzi. "Review of modelling and control of flexible-link manipulators." Proceedings of the Institution of Mechanical Engineers, Part I: Journal of Systems and Control Engineering 230.8 (2016): 861-873.
,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuum robots do not have rigid elements while multi-link flexible manipulators use "traditional" rigid links between flexible joints. One long continuous flexible material vs. a series of short flexible material segments interconnected with rigid material.

Comment: So multi-link flexible robot is more “difficult” “ complex” than continuum robots from the view of modeling. Series vs. one long flexible-link.